Reference List is not showing
I am using Overleaf
The problem is that reference list shows nothing at all.
i created a .bib file and have cited a paper there
but once combiled nothing shows
here is the code of my test.tex
\documentclass[sn-mathphys-num]{sn-jnl}% Math and Physical Sciences Numbered 
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage{multirow}%
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%
\usepackage{mathrsfs}%
\usepackage[title]{appendix}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{manyfoot}%
\usepackage{booktabs}%
\usepackage{algorithm}%
\usepackage{algorithmicx}%
\usepackage{algpseudocode}%
\usepackage{listings}%
\usepackage{makecell}

\theoremstyle{thmstyleone}%
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%  meant for continuous numbers
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}% 
\theoremstyle{thmstyletwo}%
\newtheorem{example}{Example}%
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}%

\theoremstyle{thmstylethree}%
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}%

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\title{Abcd}

\author*[1,2]{\fnm{xxx} \sur{xxx}}


\maketitle

Hello \cite{ref1}. 


\bibliography{test.bib}

\end{document}

and this is test.bib
@inproceedings{ref1,
 author = {Feurer, Matthias and Klein, Aaron and Eggensperger, Katharina and Springenberg, Jost and Blum, Manuel and Hutter, Frank},
 booktitle = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems},
 editor = {C. Cortes and N. Lawrence and D. Lee and M. Sugiyama and R. Garnett},
 pages = {},
 publisher = {Curran Associates, Inc.},
 title = {Efficient and Robust Automated Machine Learning},
 url = {https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper_files/paper/2015/file/11d0e6287202fced83f79975ec59a3a6-Paper.pdf},
 volume = {28},
 year = {2015}
}

but the page outcome is this


@Mico ooh I may even have known that once:-) thanks I'll clean up my comments here then.

What does the .blg (bibtex log) file say? Does it contain warning and/or error messages?

Off-topic: The sn-mathphys-num bibliography style would appear to require a non-empty address field for entries of type @inproceedings.
